Ember-classic-decorator not support in v2 addon components, but works fine in normal addon components
I have v2 addon to use dependencies “ember-classic-decorator”: “^3.0.0”, import in my addon component get error message. But normal addon component It’s works fine.
app.js:96 Ember.onerror handler - error.message Could not find module ember-classic-decorator imported from mail-template-editor/components/div-comp error Error: Could not find module ember-classic-decorator imported from mail-template-editor/components/div-comp
How to I resolve this issue?
what are the solutions for this issue!

There is no need for the ember-classic-decorator in v2 addons -- it was meant as an aid to help migrate from @ember/component to @glimmer/component as well as EmberObject to native classes (cerca 2019) -- since you're making a v2 addon, you're fairly up to date, and you can remove the library. It will not work with v2 addons.
